# What is the verb for causing people to stay away from an area?

Tags: word-request

In a text about the effects of holding sports events, there is a topic called "Making people flee". I want to know if there is a verb that can be used specifically instead of "making ... flee". 
As an explanation, it is maintained about the issue that holding a sports event such as the Olympics in a city causes non-sports tourists to avoid coming around. As a matter of fact, escape is not intended in its exact sense of the word. Rather, I want a transitive verb that means driving someone away from a place, here sports event place.

Comment: Would you explain a little bit more the exact sense you're looking for? Fleeing something is running away from it, so it's not exactly the same idea as avoiding something (well, unless that something is chasing you!). Residents of the city may flee before the event to avoid the crowds, but non-sport tourist would just be avoiding the city during the event, not fleeing.

Comment: Actually, fleeing might not be intended in its exact sense of the word, because there is no serious threat here for the non-sport tourists to escape from. I meant by the question I want a transitive verb that means _driving someone away from something_

Comment: Thanks! That helps my understanding quite a bit - would you edit that into your question?

Comment: you're welcome. sure I will edit the post.

Comment: You could use "expel".

Comment: "Causes non-sports tourists to avoid visiting" says "[dissuade](http://thefreedictionary.com/dissuade)" to me, but it doesn't have the connotations of "running away/fleeing", and thus, isn't perfect.

Comment: I live in a city that has many annual events that clog traffic, make businesses (particularly in the downtown area) extremely busy and make me want to flee town for somewhere quieter. I want to *escape* the crowds.

Comment: I think "repel" is the word here, as in "crowding and inaccessibility to destinations is likely to repel tourists planning on a visit during the event", with the connotation of "ugh, that's awful, I'll avoid it".

Comment: Does "vacate" fit your description?

Comment: "get away" could also work, as in "likely to make tourists get away from the event". Also, "hightail", though it's not very commonly used.

Comment: One word that isn't an exact match for fleeing or avoiding but that might be relevant is [disruption](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/disrupt). A major event like the Olympics "disrupts" the normal business and tourism of the city for many reasons - crowds, security measures, traffic, increased prices for hotel rooms, etc. The non-sports tourists may be avoiding the city because of the event, or they may want to come but can't get a hotel room at a price they want to pay.

Answer (score 1):

In that context, I'd use *"drives away"*:

*"Holding a sports event such as the Olympics in a city **drives away** non-sports tourists."*

Answer (score 0):

> Holding a sports event such as the Olympics in a city may deter non-sports tourists."

Verb - **Deter**: To discourage (someone) from doing something by instilling doubt or fear of the consequences.

past tense: **deterred**; past participle: **deterred**